# Can I return to Denmark, as a resident, without a valid passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, international-travel, uk-citizens, denmark

my passport is about to expire. I am a British citzen with a British passport. I hold an EU residency card. Would I be able to travel from the UK to Denmark without a passport, as long as I have the residency card?

This may be a stupid question, but I want to ask in case. I am worried how long it will take for a renewed passport to arrive, the same with a emergency passport.

Comment: Someone with better knowledge may answer definitively, however the UK government travel advice page indicates the answer is **No** https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/denmark/entry-requirements *If you are a resident in Denmark, you must travel with relevant documents - a valid passport, health insurance card, residence permit, residence card, EU registration certificate or personal identification document with proof of address*

Comment: As a British citizen you might be able to get a passport in one day by going to a special passport location.

Comment: @Willeke Unlikely https://homeofficemedia.blog.gov.uk/2022/07/18/factsheet-passport-processing-times-and-unprecedented-levels-of-demand/

Comment: Here's [a more specific link](https://gbr01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gov.uk%2Fget-a-passport-urgently&data=05%7C01%7CSophie.Lister%40homeoffice.gov.uk%7C461e3f72a7044e14aced08da4ee8d887%7Cf24d93ecb2914192a08af182245945c2%7C0%7C0%7C637909059207402742%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=ypC4%2B%2FC5t2pg1iYOJAbWoteZMSl%2Bf%2F3PzrZWv0V7VQ4%3D&reserved=0) about last-minute UK passport process.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica The UK press has been full of passport issuing delay horror stories for months. A last-minute process certainly exists (for a fee) however it is dependent on  getting a rare as hens-teeth appointment https://mobile.twitter.com/ukpassportcheck

Answer (score 4):

> I hold an EU residency card

Unlike the US, an EU residency card is **not** a passport replacement and must be accompanied by a valid passport.

The Schengen border code states :

> ###### Entry conditions for third-country nationals
>
> 1. For intended stays on the territory of the Member States of a duration of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period, which entails
>    considering the 180-day period preceding each day of stay, the entry
>    conditions for third-country nationals shall be the following:
>
> (a) they are in possession of a valid travel document entitling the
> holder to cross the border, satisfying the following criteria:
>
> (i) its validity shall extend at least three months after the intended
> date of departure from the territory of the Member States. In a
> justified case of emergency, this obligation may be waived;
>
> (ii) it shall have been issued within the previous 10 years;

and

> 3. On entry and exit, third-country nationals shall be subject to thorough checks as follows:
>
> (a) thorough checks on entry shall comprise verification of the
> conditions governing entry laid down in Article 6(1) and, where
> applicable, of documents authorising residence and the pursuit of a
> professional activity. This shall include a detailed examination
> covering the following aspects:
>
> > verification that the third-country national is in possession of a document which is valid for crossing the border and which has not
> > expired, and that the document **is accompanied**, where applicable, by
> > the requisite visa or residence permit;

For all intents and purposes in this case, a *valid travel document entitling the holder to cross the border* is a national passport